# Is it possible to keep AWS API Gateway custom domain when using integration proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, traefik, aws-application-load-balancer

I configured AWS API Gateway with HTTP proxy integration to an Application Load Balancer who is in front of an AWS EKS cluster. This load balancer is an ingress controller to the cluster and is managed by Traefik.

Traefik has an ingress route rule using a custom domain to forward the request to the correct backend application based on the `Host`. I added this domain and ACM certificate as part of AWS API Gateway custom domain.

When I call the API by using the custom domain it redirects to the load balancer address which was defined during the proxy integration. This request does not keep the domain as part of its URL so when the Traefik get this value `Host`, it does not identify any backend service related to it.

Is it possible to keep AWS API Gateway custom domain when using integration proxy?
The API Gateway is a new requirement only because of api key usage/metrics and the current setup without the API Gateway is working fine, then I want to keep it and add the API Gateway with minimum effort.

**Current Setup:**
Domain -> Application Load Balancer -> Traefik (Host based on Domain) -> Backend service

AWS API Gateway HTTP integration proxy reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html